# One Project Two Apps Two Static Folder - django

Tags: python, html, django, static, jinja2

I have a problem about static files,

I have two apps and I want to use different static file in each.
Like

```
{% load static1 %} 
<html><h1>App1</h1></html>

{% load static2 %} 
<html><h1>App2</h1></html>


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "app1/static1",
    BASE_DIR / "app2/static2",
]
```

Also I split my static files in each apps.

How can I do that ?

app1:
[image: app1]

app2:
[image: app2]

basedir:
[image: basedir]

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: I used bootsrap studio to design frontend and I designed two different projects so it gave me two different static folder when I exported the all code.

Comment: If you configured your `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting correctly it should consolidate them into the `STATIC_ROOT` directory when you run `manage.py collectstatic`. Doesn't that happen?

Comment: I have not configured  `STATIC_ROOT` yet, so I do not know how can I do that ?
There is same file name each static files, so two pages design are changed,but I cannot change file name because it affects all project.

Comment: That's a very broad topic to explain in a comment. I suggest you to follow a Django tutorial first. Also you can't have the same file path twice in your static assets, so you should figure out a way to rename them and/or create separate subdirectories.

Comment: Can you suggest a tutorial about this topic ?

Comment: You don't need anything specific to this topic. Just start with any basic tutorial. Check out the official one at djangoproject.com, especially part 6.